# build multidimensional JSON string with data from database

Tags: php

Well....

I have a function where I need to retrieve data from my database (which contains info for google maps markers) and build a JSON string with that data.. Since I need a multidimensional json string, I thought this would be the best option for me.

```
public function getAll(){
    $tables = ['huisartsenwachtposten', 'bioscopen'];
    $markers = [];

    for($i=0; $i<count($tables); $i++){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `:table`";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->bindParam(':table', str_replace("'", "", $tables[$i]));

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                while($row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
                    $markers[$tables[$i]][] = $row;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    return json_encode($markers);  
}
```

However, when I run this function. My browser shows me the following Error: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gepensioneerdgent.'huisartsenwachtposten'' doesn't exist"

Anyone that has a solution? :)
Thanks in advance

HS.

p.s. I have more than the 2 tables used in this example...

Comment: You can't parameterize sql, database name, table names, column names, etc. Only data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PDO, take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

bindParam() is just for columns, not for tables. You've to write down the tables names.

Try this (not tested!):

```
public function getAll(){
    $tables  = array('huisartsenwachtposten', 'bioscopen');
    $markers = array();

    for($i=0; $i<count($tables); $i++){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$tables[$i]."`";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt) {
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                while($row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
                    $markers[$tables[$i]][] = $row;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    return json_encode($markers);  
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the name of the table, so that I can have $markers[tablename][] = $row ?

Comment: So I've seen! Thanks for your help. I have an exam presentation on this on Monday, so you've been of great help! :D